# Is it allowed to put ActivityContext/ApplicationContext in a variable?

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks, static

Please tell me is it allowed to put **ActivityContext/ApplicationContext** in a variable as shown in the code below?

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {
     private val context = applicationContext

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
     }
}
```

As you know in Android, the roots of the garbage collector are: *static variables and active threads.*

Case 1. We put **applicationContext** in the `context` variable.

```
private val context = applicationContext
```

Will there be memory leak? I don't think so, because applicationContext is a singleton in the process of running the application.

Case 2. We put **activity or this** in the `context` variable.

```
private val context = this
```

Will there be memory leak? My intuition tells me not to do this. Because Activity can be destroyed (for example, when the screen is rotated). If I'm right, please explain why there will be a memory leak, because no garbage collector root is used. Maybe I'm wrong and this behavior is allowed.

**P.S.** Will the situation be similar if we put variable `context` in `companion object`?

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {
     companion object {
         private val context = applicationContext // or this
     }

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are properties, not variables. It's important to understand the distinction, although not for this particular question.

Your very first code block is fine because the application context reference will be cleared when the Activity instance is released, and Activities have shorter lifetimes than the Application.

The code example Case 1 is perfectly fine in any situation (static reference or instance reference) for the reason you said. The Application context is a singleton that lives for the lifetime of your app so it cannot be leaked.

For case 2: if you use `this` in a companion object, `this` refers to the companion object, not the Activity instance. (There would be no way for the companion object to statically get an Activity instance on its own because there is no single Activity instance for it to find at any given moment.) However, if you do this, you will indeed leak the Activity instance:

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {
     companion object {
         private var context? Context? = null
     }

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
         context = this
     }
}

// or:

private var context? Context? = null // top-level property

class MainActivity : Activity() {
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
         context = this
     }
}
```

An Activity context should never be stored in a static property.

Anything referenced by an `object` property or top-level property (outside a class) cannot be garbage collected because there is a static reference to it. Not sure what you mean by no garbage collector root being used. `object` and top-level properties are static references, which you said yourself are roots for the garbage collector.

Comment: Okey, I understood everything you said.

@Tenfour04
You have not described the most incomprehensible case (case 2). When an activity is stored in a class property and this property is not static (not in companion-object). What will happen in this situation?

Comment: The reference will prevent the instance from being released to the GC for as long as the class instance containing that reference is alive. If you reference `this` in an Activity's own property, it's just holding a reference to itself, so it won't leak, but there would be no reason to ever do this. But if you pass an Activity instance reference to some other class, you have to think about whether that class will outlive the Activity. If it's a View component in the same Activity, it's fine. If it's something like ViewModel, it's not OK.

Comment: Something is holding a reference to the Activity, or else it wouldn't exist. In this case, it is the OS, not your own code that holds what you're calling the "garbage collector root".